# Append text to the end of a line

Tags: text, append, autoit

I'm working with AutoIt, and I was wondering in there is a method I can use to append a string of text to the end of a line inside a text file. I've been browsing all over autoit forums and there are lots of answers that are really close, but I have not found a solution that has actually worked for me.

The function:

```
FileWriteLine($LOG, "FText")
```

just adds a whole new line at the bottom, while the function:

```
_FileWriteToLine($LOG, 1, "FText", 0)
```

adds the letters "FText" to the beginning of the first line in the log file.

Is there any way I can add this text to the end of the first line, instead of the beginning?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have never come up with this problem but just thinking of it, how about reading the whole line, storing it in a variable, add the extra test you want in the end of the line and then write the new line as it is modified replacing the old line???

Comment: That'll do it.  Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the FileWrite function: [FileWrite documentation](https://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/docs/functions/FileWrite.htm)

You can create your own file writing function to include the opening, writing, and closing of the file like this:

```
Func WriteToLog($FileName, $Value)
  $FileHandle = FileOpen($FileName, 1) ; 1 = append mode

  If $FileHandle <> -1 Then
    FileWrite($FileHandle, $Value)
  EndIf

  FileClose($FileHandle)
EndFunc
```

Then using your example and assuming $LOG is the file name for your log file, you can simply call your function whenever you need to log something:

```
WriteToLog($LOG, "FText")
```